# How to secure GeoServer resource - /cite/wms/**

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api

Total newbie here. I got tasked to secure the release of our GeoServer instance onto prod.

I am looking to secure the url /cite/wms?&service=WMS&request=GetMap&layers=XXXX&styles=&format=image%2Fpng&transparent=true&version=1.1.1&width=256&height=256&srs=EPSG%3A3857&bbox=1066449.418634779,7619242.979466374,1068895.4035399049,7621688.964371494

I tried to modify the rest.properties file and various settings in GeoServer interface but to no avail.

Things I tried:
/wms;GET=ADMIN
/cite/**;GET=ADMIN

How can I secure the URL (if at all possible)?

P.P. I am running docker.osgeo.org/geoserver:2.24.1 image in docker container.

Comment: Did you read the security section of the manual? There's no need to edit a file just use the gui